# Rails polymorphic association - controllers and views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

I have a model `User` (used for authentication purposes) which is connected to two other models, `Customer` and `Seller` via polymorphic association in Rails. A customer and seller must have different sign up forms because of their different data but can use a single login form because they're both `Users`. In order to manage the customer and seller resources separately, is it a good idea to create respective controllers and views for them, or should management of all Users be done in the `UsersController`?

Comment: I think instead of polymorphic association you should use Single table inheritance(STI). Customer & Seller are type of users. Then you can use single form to manage login of both the types of users.

Comment: @madyrockss I looked into Single Table Inheritance but decided against it because it involved putting a customer's data in the same table as the seller's data. It didn't make sense, because I have so many different fields. I think the table would get confusing and I would prefer to keep them in separate models, so I chose polymorphic association.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon the design of the two views customers and sellers. If the design of both the views are different then I will encourage you to create two controllers `customers_controller` and `sellers_controller` and you may want to have a module for common actions like `lib/authentication.rb`.So

```
# customers_controller.rb
include Authentication
def some_action 
end
```

and

```
 # sellers_controller.rb
include Authentication
def other_action 
end
```

Authentication file like

```
# lib/authentication.rb
module Authentication
  def common_method
  end
end
```

You can have two controllers and one module which you can write common methods/actions

Answer (score 0):

As @madyrockss pointed out, STI is probably the way to go here because User.find(params[:login]) will return either an instance of Customer or Seller automatically.

I would encourage forgetting about the UsersController and views and encourage thinking in terms of seller and customer controllers/views (that is, don't share a single controller and views per action that can handle either customer or seller and has conditionals within view determining what to show).  If the two users have different business rules, the whole thing starts to get messy real quick and becomes unwieldy to manage as business rules change.

For login/logout, if the form is going to be the same for both, then a single controller will suffice and I'd consider a different name than UsersController, such as SessionsController to be more semantically in line with what the controller's purpose is.  You are not confined to a one-to-one Models <==> Controllers <==> Views which many beginning Rails developers fall into the trap of.

Comment: Yeah, I have a SessionsController to manage logins. But I use UsersController to CRUD Users.